# JavaScript e CSS: Não sei como aumentar o tamanho do mapa e usar bem o sistema de localização

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

```js
// coleta a localização atual
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
 
    // coleta latitude e longitude
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
 
    // imprimindo mapa
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'mapa',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([latitude, longitude]),
            zoom: 6  
          })
    });
});
```

Estou aprendendo "geolocation" e não entendo bem como essa funcionalidade age e não sei como funciona o CSS, no sentido de caso eu aumentar o numero de pixels o código da erro

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>API MAPA</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapa"></div>
  <script src="14Consultando_dados_de_APIs_de_terceiros_2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
#mapa{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
```

}

Comment: eu novo aqui e não sei pq n foi o codigo JS, mas ta aqui. malz

Comment: Clique em [Editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/593456/edit) e adicione à pergunta

Comment: @RicardoPontual obg